# Linebreak in JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea, line-breaks

I'm trying to display a text from a file in a `JTextArea`. The thing is, that the `JTextArea` does not display any linebreaks. If I try to display the text in a way like this: `

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler();                 
String text = fh.loadFile("src/Files/info.txt");              

textArea = new JTextArea(text);
textArea.setSize(350, 350);
textArea.setVisible(true);
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setFocusable(false);
textArea.setBorder(null);

this.add(textArea);
```

Content of the `text` String is `Line one\nLine two\n Line three`.
The TextArea only shows the following output:
`Line one\nLine two\n Line three`

But if I manually set the text like this:

```
String text = "Line one\nLine two\n Line three"`
```

The linebreaks are shown correctly.

Comment: Beware of escaped line breaks (you don't use "\n" outside programming languages, you actually use line breaks)

Comment: Either info.txt has backslash-n's instead of actual newlines, or FileHandler.loadFile is turning newlines into backslash-n sequences.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to achieve this, however i found the simplest was to replace the new line characters with system new line characters like this :

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

So instead of printing \n as a string it will replace those when encountered with a specified system new line operator here is my example.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


    public class StackQuestions {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
                middlePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Display Area"));
                String file =readFile("file.txt");


                // create the middle panel components
                JTextArea display = new JTextArea(16, 58);
                display.setEditable(false); // set textArea non-editable
                display.setText(file);
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(display);
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

                //Add Textarea in to middle panel
                middlePanel.add(scroll);

                // My code
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(middlePanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(StackQuestions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            try {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                   line = line.replaceAll("\\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    sb.append(line);
                    //sb.append("\n");
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps in anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the content of the file, you can use a `JTextPane` instead and format your text in `HTML`:

example.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My Awesome heading</h1>

<p>This text is so<br>awesome it requires multiple<br>line<br><br>breaks!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Remember to set the content type to `text/html`:

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler();                 
String text = fh.loadFile("example.html");

JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
text.setContentType("text/html");
text.setText(text);
```

And you'll get the following in your `JFrame`:

## My Awesome heading

This text is so
awesome it requires multiple
line
breaks!